AWS: Bucket URL works but not the A-record
I have an S3 bucket configured as a static web site with public access and the standard permission policy. It's hosted in US East (region 1). The URL for this bucket works.
I've created an A-record with the same domain name, as an alias, and value s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com, which is the meat of the bucket URL. I can't ping it. Any ideas?
I expected the domain name to be recognized by the internet, but it is not, despite Route53 telling me that the new record has been synced.

PING just tells you whether PING works, and PING is often turned off on servers. The best test is one that tests what you actually want to do with the URL. Did you follow these instructions? Tutorial: Configuring a static website using a custom domain registered with Route 53 - Amazon Simple Storage Service

The process to check that a domain name is "recognized by the internet" is to perform DNS resolution of that name to one or more IP addresses e.g. using dig.

I did use the process specified in the tutorial. Here is the A-record. The resource was taken from the resource dropdown list. Do you see a problem?
craininsurancellc.net
A
Simple



Yes
s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com

I've never heard of anyone pinging an s3 bucket before. That requires the underlying server to accept ICMP requests.
You should curl instead of ping here to fetch the actual contents of the bucket. Or you know, just try loading the content on your browser.
